# Unable to override content disposition header in s3

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I'm using the following php function to give temporary access to the public for a private file.

```
function get_s3_signed_url($bucket, $resource, $AWS_S3_KEY, $AWS_s3_secret_key, $expire_seconds) {
    $expires = time()+$expire_seconds;
    // S3 Signed URL creation
    $string_to_sign = "GET\n\n\n{$expires}\n/".str_replace(".s3.amazonAWS.com","", $bucket)."/$resource";
    $signature = urlencode(base64_encode((hash_hmac("sha1", utf8_encode($string_to_sign), $AWS_s3_secret_key, TRUE))));

    $authentication_params = "AWSAccessKeyId=".$AWS_S3_KEY;
    $authentication_params.= "&Expires={$expires}";
    $authentication_params.= "&Signature={$signature}";

    return $link = "http://s3.amazonAWS.com/{$bucket}/{$resource}?{$authentication_params}";
}
```

I wanted to add the content disposition header so I can change the filename to `test.mp3` when a user tries to access this url which defaults the filename to `982jdjd2p3.mp3`

```
$privateUrl = array('privateUrl' => get_s3_signed_url('testbucket', '982jdjd2p3.mp3', $my_aws_key, $my_aws_secret_key, 60));
```

I tried adding the following line of code to the function

```
$file_name = 'test.mp3';       
$authentication_params.= "&Content-Disposition={$file_name}";
```

However when I click on the url

`http://s3.amazonAWS.com/testbucket/982jdjd2p3.mp3?AWSAccessKeyId=***&Expires=***&Signature=***&Content-Disposition=test.mp3`

The proposed filename is to be saved as `982jdjd2p3.mp3`

How do I override the content disposition header for s3 GET requests using this function?

**See Also**

[Amazon S3 Change file download name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611432/amazon-s3-change-file-download-name)

**EDIT**

Here is the most recent attempt to rename the file with a get request using this function.

```
function get_s3_signed_url($bucket, $resource, $AWS_S3_KEY, $AWS_s3_secret_key, $expire_seconds) {
    $expires = time()+$expire_seconds;
    // S3 Signed URL creation
    $filename='moot.mp3';
    $disposition = "response-content-disposition=" . urlencode("attachment; filename={$filename}");            

    $string_to_sign = "GET\n\n\n{$expires}\n/".str_replace(".s3.amazonAWS.com","", $bucket)."/$resource";
    $string_to_sign .= "?{$disposition}";
    $signature = urlencode(base64_encode((hash_hmac("sha1", utf8_encode($string_to_sign), $AWS_s3_secret_key, TRUE))));

    $authentication_params = "AWSAccessKeyId=".$AWS_S3_KEY;  
    $authentication_params.= "&Expires={$expires}";
    $authentication_params.= "&Signature={$signature}";
    $authentication_params.= "&{$disposition}";

    return $link = "http://s3.amazonAWS.com/{$bucket}/{$resource}?{$authentication_params}";
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem with your function is that the header values should be encoded in the final hyperlink, but not for signing. The following function corrects that:

```
function get_s3_signed_url($bucket, $resource, $AWS_S3_KEY, $AWS_s3_secret_key, $expire_seconds, $save_as)
{
    $expires = time()+$expire_seconds;
    // S3 Signed URL creation
    $headers = array(
        'response-content-disposition' => 'attachment; filename=' . $save_as,
    );
    $resource = str_replace(array('%2F', '%2B'), array('/', '+'), rawurlencode($resource));

    $string_to_sign = "GET\n\n\n$expires\n/$bucket/$resource";
    $final_url = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/$bucket/$resource?";

    $append_char = '?';
    foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
        $final_url .= $header . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
        $string_to_sign .= $append_char . $header . '=' . $value;
        $append_char = '&';
    }

    $signature = urlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $string_to_sign, $AWS_s3_secret_key, true)));

    return $final_url . "AWSAccessKeyId=$AWS_S3_KEY&Expires=$expires&Signature=$signature";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jack! However, it only saves as the title up until the first space.  For example if `$save_as='hello world';` the file would be saved as `hello`.  Any way around this?

Comment: @user784637 in that case you would want to consider adding double quotes around it, e.g. `filename="hello world.txt"`

Answer (score 1):

Format of your [Content-Disposition](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html) is invalid, Specify `disposition-type`.

Example:
`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.mp3;`

Use `response-content-disposition` in signature and params:

```
$disposition = "response-content-disposition=" . urlencode("attachment; filename={$filename}");
/* ... */
$string_to_sign .= "?{$disposition}";
/* ... */
$authentication_params.= "&{$disposition}";
```

Comment: I'm confused about where to make that change, can I do it in the above php script? What's the appropriate code?

Comment: Unfortunately when I try that I get a link to an .xml page with the following error **The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.**

Comment: probably you forgot to add `content-disposition` in signature

Comment: Thanks bernard - I'll try this when I get back home

Comment: Sorry bernard - this syntax is incorrect, pls see my edit for the current function I'm using