# Supplying Headers To Amazon S3 with FineUploader

Tags: amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I am using FineUploader to upload files to Amazon S3, and I would like to add the `Content-Disposition` header to the files. I have tried this (in CoffeeScript):

```
request:
      endpoint: "..."
      accessKey: "...
      customHeaders:
        "Content-Disposition": "attachment;"
```

This hasn't worked for me. Any tips on what I should do instead?

Thanks.

Comment: Please see https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/1214.  In the meantime, you can generate a signed URL server-side  using the AWS SDK with the proper override header for content-disposition and use that client-side.

Comment: Got it. This is for a web app written in Scala, and rather than import another jar file for the sake of a workaround on a feature that isn't high-priority, I am content to wait until your team gets around to adding this feature. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment this is a feature request to be addressed as described in [#1214](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/1214).

Until that is complete, you can generate a signed URL server-side using the AWS SDK with the proper override header for content-disposition and use that client-side.  This is possible via the S3 API, and several SDKs probably expose signed URL generation and header overrides.  I noticed that the [scala SDK](https://github.com/seratch/AWScala) does the former, but not the latter.  Here is another SO case that addresses this in PHP though: [Unable to override content disposition header in s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557980/unable-to-override-content-disposition-header-in-s3).